# Copy Database using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I want to quickly overwrite one database with another (preferably using the GUI in Management Studio).

Basically I have `DB1` and `DB2`. `DB1` is an older version of `DB2` which I need to overwrite, so `DB1 = DB2`.

I have tried the following;

- Right Clicking Databases
- Clicking Restore Databases
- Selecting the From Database to select DB2 (But for some reason it is not appearing here?)

Any Ideas? I have not been given permissions to create new databases on the system, so I am looking to simple over write the existing database, rather than create, drop, rename, etc.

Comment: just backup and drop the two database, and restore the correct database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Back up DB2
- Restore DB1 from the backup of DB2

Comment: Ok. I backed up db2 with no issues. Then I right clicked and went to restore db1 from the file I just created from the back up. I got a user does not have permission to restore error here. Now db2 is stuck in the restoring state?? I have tried using RESTORE DATABASE WITH REcOVERY but I get the same user does not have permission to restore error? Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Permissions to create databases are different from permissions to restore databases. But it sounds like you don't have permission to do either. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29340/sql-server-permissions-to-create-restore-delete-only-some-databases